# DSL for holding resources

Tags: scala, dsl

Can anyone help me build a DSL for holding resources? I want to use it similar to Java's `synchronized`, so that if a resource (java: an object monitor) is already acquired it won't get acquired again! (For the following example resources are assumed to be of type `Int`)

```
object Holding {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

    HoldResource(1,2,3) {
      // holding resource 1,2,3
      println("!")
      HoldResource(3) {
        // still holding resource 1,2,3 (but not acquiring resource 3 again!!!)
        println("*")
      }
      println("!!")
      HoldResource(4,5) {
        // holding resource 1,2,3,4,5
        println("#")
      }
      println("!!!")
    }
    // all resources are freed
  }
}
```

Until now my ROUGH approach looks like this (that means I know about the `try { ... } finally { ... }` resource-pattern.) :

```
object HoldResource {
  class Context(val resources: Seq[Int]) {
    def apply[A](f: => A): A = {
      try { f } finally {
        // free resources
      }
    }
  }
  def apply[A](resources: Int*): Context = {
    // lock/acquire resources
    new Context(resources)
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really need a domain specific _language_ for what you want, or just a single construct that does what you need?

Comment: Ok, Probably my understanding of a dsl is somewhat different. A construct that does the job is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're after Software Transactional Memory.

Try these articles to get you started:

- [STM in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/software-transactional-memory-in-scala)
- [Improving STM with MVCC](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/improving-the-stm-multi-version-concurrency-control)

There's also some useful material on resource management:

- [Article: ARM blocks in Scala](http://polyglot-window.blogspot.com/2008/02/arm-blocks-in-scala.html)
- [Github: scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm/wiki)